Extract all strings having a common substring in notepad++
I would like to know if I can use notepad++ or tcl to extract all words containing "_Ori" from below
Example text:

R_yu_rfe_h2c_PSM_to_LTSV       yoc_cu_h2c_PSM      hrr_cti_h2c_LhSV    '(R_tyoc_cfi_h2c_tsv_Ori * R_lnoc_cfi_h2c_tsv_Scaler)/(oorc_cfi_h2c_psb_Ori * yroc_cfi_h2c_psb_Scaler)'
R_eesf_sb_PSM_to_LTSV       yosf_sb_PSM     madser_sb_LTr   '(R_ptysf_sb_tsv_Ori * R_peef_sb_tsv_Scaler)/(piy_sb_psb_Ori * yyf_sb_psb_Scaler)'
R_pttf_dfx_PSM_to_LTSV      usf_dfx_PSM     uiosf_dfx_LTSV  '(R_piui_dfx_tsv_Ori * R_pyf_dfx_tsv_Scaler)/(ufsf_dfx_psb_Ori * lksf_dfx_psb_Scaler)'

Expected Output:

R_tyoc_cfi_h2c_tsv_Ori
R_ptysf_sb_tsv_Ori
piy_sb_psb_Ori
R_piui_dfx_tsv_Ori
R_piui_dfx_tsv_Ori
ufsf_dfx_psb_Ori


What have you tried so far?

you can probably use both ... wouldn't  you rather want to know how, instead of just if?

Use this very basic regex:
\w+_Ori

Where \w stands for word character (i.e.: [a-zA-Z0-9_])
